# Hibernate Timezone Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities in two different services and two different databases and both of them have one DateTime column in common

when I want to set an exact time for both columns, in one of the services the time is right but in another one time is set for two hours ago

Save Query in first entity ( wrong time ) :

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE PlatformOrganization p SET p.paymentsMatchingLastUpdate = :time WHERE p.externalUUID = :organizationExternalUUID")
void updatePaymentsMatchingLastUpdateByExternalUUID(@Param("organizationExternalUUID") String organizationExternalUUID, @Param("time") LocalDateTime time);
```

save Query in second entity ( right time ) :

```
public PlatformResponse<ImportConfigurationDto> updateConfigurationPaymentsMatchingLastUpdate(LocalDateTime updateTime, String externalUUID) {
    ImportConfiguration configuration = importConfigurationDao.findByExternalUUID(externalUUID);

    if (configuration == null)
        return new PlatformResponse<>("configuration not found");

    configuration.setPaymentsMatchingLastUpdate(updateTime);
    importConfigurationDao.save(configuration);

    return new PlatformResponse<>(mapper.mapToDto(configuration));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of **`Datetime` you store in Database** and **`Datetime` you define in DTO Object**.

Can you share more about it?

In case you use Spring Boot. Config in `properties` file to give you more info:

```
# Show SQL Query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Show Binding
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

# Show details patch and transaction
logging.level.ROOT=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

I think the issue because the converter in @Query
If use spring you can use:

```
@Component
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

  @Override
  public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    if (localDateTime == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
    if (timestamp == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp.getTime()),
        ZoneId.systemDefault());
  }
}
```

Comment: im using LocalDateTime and in database im using DATETIME